# Login mechanism using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Hi in my application login is working fine but one problem is for example my password is- **secret**  if i enter **SECRET** with capital or **SEcret** also it is logging in, If i give wrong password it will return false any solution

Login Controller

```
app.controller('LoginController',function(loginService, $rootScope,$scope, $http,$location) {

     $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.log=loginService.getLogin( $scope.emailId , $scope.password).
         then(function (response) {
            console.log($scope.log);
            console.log(response)
                     if (response.data.LoginVerificationResult.length === 0) {
                        alert('details are not Available for this emailId');
                        $scope.error=true;

                     } else {
                         $rootScope.name=response.data.LoginVerificationResult[0].UserName;
                         $scope.abc=response.data.LoginVerificationResult[0].UserType
                 console.log($scope.abc+"from.......");
                         sessionStorage.setItem("EmaiId",$scope.emailId);
                         sessionStorage.setItem("User Id",response.data.LoginVerificationResult[0].UserID);
                         sessionStorage.setItem("UserName",response.data.LoginVerificationResult[0].UserName);
                         sessionStorage.setItem("UserType",response.data.LoginVerificationResult[0].UserType);

                            $scope.UserType = sessionStorage.getItem("UserType");
                            console.log($scope.UserType +"from login controller")

                            if ($scope.UserType =='Hr') {
                                 $location.path('/empRegister')
                            }
                            else if ($scope.UserType =='Admin') {
                                $location.path('/patientRegister')
                            }
                            else {
                                 $location.path('/dashboard')
                            }


                     }

         });
     };
});
```

All scenarios are working fine but problem is with password mentioned above

Comment: I don't think that you can do something from your controller. You should add a *case_sensitive* match where your authentication takes place. If it's not in your `loginService` then it should be somewhere in your server. Do you mind posting the `loginService` and the code snippet that matches the credentials?

Comment: @JonathanLa'Fey means it should be in API side

Comment: Probably. Currently the password matching is *case_insensitive*. You should find where this matching happens and do it *case_sensitive*. You can post the API method that matches credentials if you want help with that

Comment: @JonathanLa'Fey as u told in API side they added case sensitive now it is working fine

Comment: Ok, should i add it as an answer for you to accept it?

Comment: @JonathanLa'Fey one doubt not related to this question, How to hide the application code from Sources tab in browser developer tool

Comment: I am guessing that your password match is done in the database? Sql queries usually are case-insensitive (this actually depends on the collationtype of your fields). 

If you are matching passwords using sql queries, are you aware that it is bad practice to store password unencrypted?

Comment: This sure is completely unrelated. In my knowledge, you can't hide `javascript` code from appearing in browser. Feel free to post an new question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password matching is happening **server-side**.

Currently is set to match your passwords in a `case-insensitive` way. You should change this to match `case-sensitive` passwords